# Bash script for ssh in remote servers and continue if prompt for password

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I need to see if i can ssh into a list of multiple servers (near 200). I know that to some of them I can login with my public key  and in others I can´t (asking for password).
I created a bash script that  ssh to a list of servers and execute  hostname command , continues and save results into a log file. But when I want to ssh to a server that  asks for password, script get stuck obviously.
Is there a Way to do a `CTRL C` when this happends and continue with the rest of the list?

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for host in $(cat servers.txt)
do
        ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "$host" "hostname"
done > test.log
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be sufficient to pass `-o PasswordAuthentication=no` on the SSH command line?

Comment: that did the trick, thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39635/117549 ?